# "Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS" when using `adb shell pm grant` command

Tags: adb, permissions, shell, copy-paste

I have installed a clipboard manager, [Clip Stack](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.catchingnow.tinyclipboardmanager) on my Android 11 phone. When the app is opened, the developer helpfully gives the message that background clipboard access has been blocked by Android 10 but he has found a workaround and to run the following ADB commands:

> ```
> adb -d shell appops set com.catchingnow.tinyclipboardmanager SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW allow; 
> adb -d shell pm grant com.catchingnow.tinyclipboardmanager android.permission.READ_LOGS; 
> adb shell am force-stop com.catchingnow.tinyclipboardmanager;
> ```

I don't want to install Android Studio. I tried the following:

1. Enabled Developer Options on my phone and turned on USB debugging and Allow screen overlaps on settings
2. On my computer installed [minimal_adb_fastboot_v1.4.3](https://androidmtk.com/download-minimal-adb-and-fastboot-tool)
3. Connected my phone to my computer via usb
4. Clicked on the desktop shortcut for Minimal ADB and Fastboot to open a cmd window
5. Ran `adb -d shell appops set com.catchingnow.tinyclipboardmanager SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW allow;` The daemon started.
6. Ran `adb -d shell pm grant com.catchingnow.tinyclipboardmanager android.permission.READ_LOGS;` It gave error:

```
Exception occurred while executing 'grant':
java.lang.SecurityException: grantRuntimePermission: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS.
        at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:2028)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:2056)
        at com.android.server.pm.permission.PermissionManagerService.grantRuntimePermissionInternal(PermissionManagerService.java:1463)
        at com.android.server.pm.permission.PermissionManagerService.grantRuntimePermission(PermissionManagerService.java:1444)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runGrantRevokePermission(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2300)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:251)
        at android.os.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:98)
        at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:44)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:22307)
        at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:929)
        at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:813)
        at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:4687)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4471)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1159)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: Regarding the error you're getting, was the workaround written in context to your exact model device?  AFAIK the OEM can intervene with permission configurations so these types of workarounds usually are not one-size-fits-all.  There used to be a method of "borrowing" a different user to grant permissions (like on some...

Comment: ...versions of FireOS, where you can "use" Facebook's user to disable OEM apps).  You might want to try XDA as well, under your device's board/thread.

Comment: workaround for android 10, you have android 11

Comment: I see a similar problem with Logcat Reader that worked with Android 8.0, but now fails (on another device) with Android 12. Seems Android 12 does not allow that anymore, or is there an additional setting needed?

Comment: See also https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/unable-to-grant-permissions-using-adb.3812658/

Answer (score 1):

For Oppos Color OS 12.1 (Android 12) this worked for me:

I *disabled* the option (sorry: it's German): "**Über USB installierte Apps prüfen**" (probably "Check apps installed via USB"):

[image: Developer Setting in Oppo's Color OS 12.2]

After that the command `adb shell pm grant com.dp.logcatapp android.permission.READ_LOGS` succeeded.
Before I got:

> java.lang.SecurityException: grantRuntimePermission: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS.